# How to Divide an array in to segments and then do sub segments of the segments using python numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I want to do divide an 8*8 array in to 4 segments(each segment of 4*4 array) as shown below in step2. Then again divide each segment in to other small 4 subsegemnts(each subsegment of 2*2 array) and then find the mean of each subsegment and then find the stabbndard deviation of each segment using the 4 means of the 4 subsegments in it. So that finally I only have an array (2*2 array) ie with 1 standard deviation for 1 segment.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_blocks

arr=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]])

img= view_as_blocks(arr, block_shape=(4,4))
```

upto this I have tried but I was unable to go further in my requirement as I am completely new to python and numpy. Kindly, help me in achieve my requirement.

```
#step1-Array
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])

#step2-segments
array([[[[1, 2, 3, 4],
         [1, 2, 3, 4],
         [1, 2, 3, 4],
         [1, 2, 3, 4]],

        [[5, 6, 7, 8],
         [5, 6, 7, 8],
         [5, 6, 7, 8],
         [5, 6, 7, 8]]],


       [[[1, 2, 3, 4],
         [1, 2, 3, 4],
         [1, 2, 3, 4],
         [1, 2, 3, 4]],

        [[5, 6, 7, 8],
         [5, 6, 7, 8],
         [5, 6, 7, 8],
         [5, 6, 7, 8]]]])

**more steps to go to get final output**
```

**Expected Output**

```
([[1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0]])
```

Comment: Then what do you do with the means?

Comment: So, the output would be `(4,4)` shaped, right?

Comment: @gmds I want to calculate the standard deviation of the each segment using the 4 means of their respective subsegments in it.

Comment: @Divakar the output would be (2,2). one standard deviation for one segment.

Comment: @SaiKiran So you mean, calculate the standard deviations of the means of the 4 subsegments, for each of the 4 segments?

Comment: Can you show us the expected output and preferably use random data?

Comment: @gmds exactly. that is what I am expecting the output should be.

Comment: @SaiKiran Understood, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Divakar Please check the question now. I included the expected output  for the same given array.

Comment: Can you show us how did you arrive at those results?

Comment: @Divakar I calculated those results manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using a function `view_as_blocks` of `skimage.util.shape`.